# Flat Riemannian manifolds with boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

The universal cover of a flat, connected, complete Riemannian manifold is Euclidean space, which allows for classification of all such manifolds as quotient spaces $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ for torsionfree crystallographic groups $\Gamma \leq O(n)\ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$. Are there any similar results pertaining to flat manifolds *with boundary*? A classification is probably out of reach, but even partial (in particular, positive) results would help. For instance, submanifolds of the above flat manifolds would be examples; are there others?

Comment: Do you require anything of the boundary?  Should it be totally geodesic, etc?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I don't have anything in mind, except they be sufficiently well-behaved in order to be able to say anything reasonable.